# What LEGO piece is above the blaster with clip?

Tags: part-identification

[image: \[!\[lego star wars \]\[1\]\]\[1\]]

I can’t seem to find this exact piece. I was wondering if you could help me find it?

Comment: Those black stripes tell me that the image is a still from a video, and I'm assuming it's from the 2022 "Skywalker Saga" videogame. It'd be nice to have a reference to the original video in order to give a bit more context to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Looks exactly like the microphone minifig utensil:

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=90370

However according to bricklink, it does not exist in blue.
Then again, neither does a technic half pin come in lime, so this is likely a render than an actual build

**Update:** There was a question about the blaster with clip in the comments, that blaster does exist:
[image]
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15445

But again it does not come in the color depicted, just black and dark bluish gray

Comment: Thank you. That’s a shame. I’ll just use other colours

Comment: Isn't there no clip like that, either (a double clip)?

Comment: @Davidw. updated my answer in response to your question

Comment: Ah, I was thinking it was one of the (better looking) more traditional Star Wars style blasters.

Comment: Definitely a render (probably from the 2022 Skywalker Saga video game), the minifig geometry, the lighting, and the materials are all dead giveaways (even aside from the color mismatch with real parts).

Comment: Green and blue are weird colors for a gun anyhow.  I don't think they were ever depicted in those colors in any of the films (though maybe in the LEGO Star Wars shorts - I haven't watched all of those.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I don't think bananas were depicted in the films either

Comment: I think that's with the "Comedy Weapons" option enabled - this turns the weapons into silly "everyday" items - Han's blaster is a banana, and I think this is supposed to be a water-pistol (i.e. a Super Soaker or similar).